# Using the TList class to reorder multiple fields

Tags: c++, c++builder

```
int __fastcall ListSortFunc1(void *Item1, void *Item2)
{
    MyStruct *item1 = (MyStruct*)Item1;
    MyStruct *item2 = (MyStruct*)Item2;

    return (item1->string1 < item2->string1) ? (item1->string1 > item2->string1) :
            StrToInt64(item1->number1) - StrToInt64(item2->number1);
}
```

Reading the online documentation, it is not very clear how to use the `Sort` method.

My need is to reorder two or more fields. Currently, I have to reorder a file where the first field is numeric, the second is the date, the third a string, the fourth still a string.

I did some tests with Excel and with the code that it reports, but I get completely different results.

Can anyone kindly provide me with directions?

Comment: `(item1->string1 > item2->string1)` must be `false` when `(item1->string1 < item2->string1)` is `true`. Why do you even check that? Your `return` statement looks wrong.

Comment: I don't check the return value. Unfortunately, I cannot find documentation where it explains in detail the use of the Sort () method.

Comment: @David then you [didn't look very hard](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TListSortCompare)

Comment: I would advise against doing `StrToInt64(item1->number1) - StrToInt64(item2->number1)` - if the numbers are very large you can hit arithmetic overflow (your big positive suddenly becomes negative so the sort misbehaves).  With int64 you'll probably get away with it in most cases, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TList::Sort()` is passed a callback function that is called during sorting to compare pairs of values from the list. The callback is expected to conform to the specification of the [`TListSortCompare`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TListSortCompare) type. Per its documentation:

> `Item1` and `Item2` are 2 elements from the list. When these are passed to the `TListSortCompare` function, the Sort method is asking which order they should be in. The comparison returns a value determined by the relative values of `Item1` and `Item2`, as shown in this table:
>
> | Value | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | >0 (positive) | `Item1` is greater than `Item2` |
> | 0 | `Item1` is equal to `Item2` |
> | <0 (negative) | `Item1` is less than `Item2` |

Your function does not satisfy that requirement.

When `item1->string1` is less than `item2->string1`, you are returning 0 when you should be returning a negative value.

Otherwise, you return the result of subtracting `item2->number1` from `item1->number1`. But you are comparing the `number1` fields when `item1->string1` is greater than or equal to `item2->string1`. You should be comparing the `number1` fields only when the `string1` fields are equal.  Also, you are risking overflows by using subtraction if the `number1` fields have large values.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
int __fastcall ListSortFunc1(void *Item1, void *Item2)
{
    MyStruct *item1 = static_cast<MyStruct*>(Item1);
    MyStruct *item2 = static_cast<MyStruct*>(Item2);

    if (item1->string1 == item2->string1)
    {
        // simply subtracting the values could lead to integer overflows
        // for large values, so just compare the values as-is...

        // Also: why are these not stored as __int64 to begin with?
        __int64 int1 = StrToInt64(item1->number1);
        __int64 int2 = StrToInt64(item2->number1);

        if (int1 < int2) return -1;
        if (int1 > int2) return 1;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return (item1->string1 < item2->string1) ? -1 : 1;
        // or:
        return CompareStr(item1->string1, item2->string1); // case sensitive
        // or:
        return CompareText(item1->string1, item2->string1); // case insensitive
    }
}
```